# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without measure node

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

When running react native code for android i get the below error. (Screenshot)

I know the problem is probably im missing a tag

However the code base is huge is there a way to know specifically which tag and where it is that is causing the problem?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: check with the component proptype

Comment: Try checking the last file you modified and post the code for it

Comment: Sorry I'm noob with react. What /where is the component prototype? @karthik

Comment: From what I read the error only shows with Android. And this is the first time i try it with android. So it might not be related to the last modification. @Pritish Vaidya

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you wrongly put comments in render method where you write your view's code. This issue also occurs when there is bad indentation, and even if you put two tags in one line, like:

`<View> <Text> Hello Yoganode error </Text> </View>`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when I had comments on the same line as a tag in my render() method.

Like this:

```
</Animated.View> {/* End of Signpost View */}
```

Moving comment to a new line helped:

```
</Animated.View> 
{/* End of Signpost View */}
```